# Facebook upload photo from computer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to make a facebook app that uploads photos from the computer to a specific album on facebook. i have the code below but i get an error: failed creating formpost data.

```
  require_once 'include.php';
  $config = array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
);
 $facebook = new Facebook($config);

 $user = $facebook->getUser();

 if($user && isset($_POST['submit'])){  
try {       
 $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

//Create an album
$album_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Album desc',
    'name'=> 'Album name'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'POST', $album_details);

//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Upload a photo to album of ID...
$photo = realpath($_FILES['miss_photo']['tmp_name']);
$photo2 = $photo . '.jpg';
//echo $photo2; exit();

$photo_details['image'] = '@' . $photo2;

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'POST', $photo_details);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo ($e->getMessage());
 }
}
else
echo 'error';
```

any idea why i get the error message?

Comment: no,the error is failed creating formpost data and is certainly about the file name. but what?

Comment: Have you moved the file from the temp folder to a real place?

Comment: nope. this may be the problem?

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

You cant use files in that way, you need to provide path to your file, like:

```
photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'some test'
);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('/path/to/your/image_file.jpg');
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i don't have the path. the file is stored in my computer. in the computer of the user that uploads it i mean.